# How to change button state and dispatch action to redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, salesforce-lightning

I have an event listener listening for click events and am running this function:

```
  handleClick = e => {
    const neutralState =
      "slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-m-around_xx-small";
    const selectedState =
      "slds-button slds-button_brand slds-m-around_xx-small";
    const target = e.currentTarget;
    const targetClass = target.getAttribute("class");
    const value = target.innerHTML;

    if (targetClass === neutralState) {
      target.setAttribute("class", selectedState);
      this.saveData(value, this.props.modifier);
    } else if (targetClass === selectedState) {
      target.setAttribute("class", neutralState);
      this.removeData(value, this.props.modifier);
    }
  };

  saveData(value, modifier) {
    if (modifier === "kinds of loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(addKindsOfLoss(value));
    } else if (modifier === "type of loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(addTypeOfLoss(value));
    } else if (modifier === "water loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(addWaterLoss(value));
    }
  }

  removeData(value, modifier) {
    if (modifier === "kinds of loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(removeKindsOfLoss(value));
    } else if (modifier === "type of loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(removeTypeOfLoss(value));
    } else if (modifier === "water loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(removeWaterLoss(value));
    }
  }
```

The saveData and removeData actions basically add items or remove items from an array.

So in my handleClick function, if I comment out the functions for `this.saveData` and `this.removeData` the buttons change as expected. But if the `saveData` and `removeData` functions are in place, the change does not happen. It basically stays at the neutral state for the button.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong or have any suggestion on how to be able to change the button state and fire the action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a small program with your code segment. It is working as you expected. It changes the class in the button as you expected.

```
const root = document.getElementById("root");

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
       super(props);
   }

  handleClick = e => {
    const neutralState =
      "slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-m-around_xx-small";
    const selectedState =
      "slds-button slds-button_brand slds-m-around_xx-small";
    const target = e.currentTarget;
    const targetClass = target.getAttribute("class");
    const value = target.innerHTML;

    if (targetClass === neutralState) {
      target.setAttribute("class", selectedState);
      this.saveData(value, this.props.modifier);
    } else if (targetClass === selectedState) {
      target.setAttribute("class", neutralState);
      this.removeData(value, this.props.modifier);
    }
  };

  saveData(value, modifier) {
    if (modifier === "kinds of loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(addKindsOfLoss(value));
    } else if (modifier === "type of loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(addTypeOfLoss(value));
    } else if (modifier === "water loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(addWaterLoss(value));
    }
  }

  removeData(value, modifier) {
    if (modifier === "kinds of loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(removeKindsOfLoss(value));
    } else if (modifier === "type of loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(removeTypeOfLoss(value));
    } else if (modifier === "water loss") {
      this.props.dispatch(removeWaterLoss(value));
    }
  }

   render() {
       return(
           <div>
               <input type="button" value="button" class="slds-button slds-button_neutral slds-m-around_xx-small" onClick={this.handleClick} />
           </div>
       );
   }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

I am not sure any issues with the special methods addKindsOfLoss, removeKindsOfLoss etc. but the on click action is triggered.